# How do you encode getmessage calls in the following code below?

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, getmessage

Im trying to HTML/JavaScript ecode the getmessage calls in the code listed below. Can someone explain how to properly do this? The code below is a snippet from a program which is used to handle a failed authentication attempt. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
        logger.debug("Authentication Failure: " + exception.getMessage());
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Authentication Failed: " + exception.getMessage());
```

Comment: Please tell us what that code does and does not. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @kebs I made changes to the original question which hoepfully better explains the question.